# What happened to the star feature to indicate a question that one really liked?

Tags: discussion

Way back when, one could click on a star to mark a question that one really liked.  Now there seems to be just a bookmark feature.

**Is the star gone?**

Bookmarking is not the same thing at all.  One might want to bookmark a dreadful question to pull it up as an Peculiar or Awful Example of something.

I know there is no point in complaining about anything here that Rory cannot fix.  But, Hell.

Comment: The star was not for liking the question, but to stare at it (to be notified about the answers and comments(.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the star ('favorite') has been replaced by the bookmark. See [Favorites are now known as Bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347558/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

> Bookmarking is not the same thing at all. One might want to bookmark a dreadful question to pull it up as an Peculiar or Awful Example of something.

That's exactly where people were also using the favorite button for, according to research:

> - The new name reflects more accurately the way that the tool is used (and removes confusion that many users had about the term Favorite and what it implies).

One way to bring the old functionality back (at least for you) would be to install a userscript to change the buttons (and names). [I've done so for another change I didn't like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329688/295232); I'm not aware of a script for this change, but perhaps you could [request one](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script-request).

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel.  I used the star to reward a user beyond just one upvote.  I will reconsider the usefulness of the bookmark.